# iOS Adding CAShapeLayer is not showing on runtime

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I have a textfield, added from storyboard, trying to add line in bottom of textfield using CAShapeLayer and BeizerPath

```
extension UITextField {

    func getLine() {
        let x1 = self.frame.origin.x
        let y = self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height
        let start = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y)

        let x2 = self.frame.origin.x + self.frame.size.width
        let end = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y)

        print("\(start) \(end)")

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Usage :  txtFiled.getLine()

But it is not showing. 
Let me know what missed or anything incorrect doing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your coordinate calculation for the bezier path. You are using textfields frame's origin for your path. You should use bounds origin for calculation your path's coordinate as you are adding the path to UITextField not the container. Corrected code below:

```
extension UITextField {

    func getLine() {
        let x1 = self.bounds.origin.x
        let y = self.bounds.origin.y + self.frame.size.height
        let start = CGPoint(x: x1, y: y)

        let x2 = self.bounds.origin.x + self.frame.size.width
        let end = CGPoint(x: x2, y: y)

        print("\(start) \(end)")

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Checkoout [apple's doc on view programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html)